# Elasticserach NEST Client doesn't bind _score nor _id in searchresults

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm using the NEST Client for searching in an elastic db with a .net core application.

Everything works fine except that neither the `_id` nor the `_score` field is bound.

All other fields e.g. the timestamp are filled.

I also tried to use the `[Number (Name="_score")]` and the `[Text(Name="_id")]` attributes but the fields are always empty / default values

What am I missing?

```
 public sealed class ElasticMapping
    {
        [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("_id")]
        public string ElasticId { get; set; }

        [PropertyName("_score")]
        public Nullable<double> Score { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those fields dont need to exists in your documents, they are metafileds that get added to the hits by elastic when it returns the result. You could set a breakpoint and inspect the result that is returned, take a look at the hits property.